# Page Setup Macro Not Making All Changes to Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro in VBA to loop through all the sheets in my workbook and set them up in a particular way.

If I step through the macro all works well, but when I let it run automatically, not all the changes take effect.

A light version of my macro is as follows:

```
Sub SetUpPage()

Dim wks As Worksheet

    If Application.Version >= 14 Then
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
    End If

    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        wks.PageSetup.PrintArea = wks.UsedRange.Address

        With wks.PageSetup
            .PaperSize = xlPaper11x17
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .Order = xlDownThenOver
            .Zoom = 80

            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .PrintHeadings = False
            .PrintGridlines = False
            .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
            .PrintQuality = 600
            .CenterHorizontally = False
            .CenterVertically = False
            .Draft = False
            .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
            .BlackAndWhite = False
            .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        End With
    Next wks

    If Application.Version >= 14 Then
        Application.PrintCommunication = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The main, but not the only, problem is it doesn't set the `.PaperSize = xlPaper11x17` correctly.

I thought I might have been the `Application.PrintCommunication = False`, so I commented those lines out, but still same issue.

I tried activating the desired worksheet during execution.

I'm on Excel 2007 on Win 7 x64.

Comment: Which bits don't work?

Comment: @Rory, I think the main bit is the part of setting the page size to 11x17, but others too... Kind of haphazardly....

Comment: Might require a slight change to your code, but what if, instead of looping, you selected all sheets, then changed the print details? Then unselected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I could navigate around this issue - Still doesn't make perfect sense to me - was to move around the order of the properties being set....

It did seem to make a big difference (although I don't know why)  to change the order to:

```
With wks.PageSetup
    .Zoom = 80
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PaperSize = xlPaper11x17

    .PrintQuality = 600
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Draft = False
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed

    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
End With
```

---

I also implemented @guitarthrowers suggestion from the above comments:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Select
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    ....
End With
```

But that didn't have much to do with this specific issue... It did, however, offer definite performance gains over looping through each sheet separately.

Hope this manages to help someone else....

Answer (score 1):

Although `Application.PrintCommunication` is meant to speed up the application of PageSetup settings, sometimes, in my experience, it prevents some settings from being applied. Hope this helps somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PrintCommunication to False to enable repeating the title row

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$15:$15"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
```

You can then set the  PrintCommunication to True to continue with the rest of the PageSetup

```
Application.PrintCommunication = True
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup



        .LeftHeader = "&G"
        .LeftHeaderPicture.fileName = ImagePath
        .LeftHeaderPicture.Height = 200
        .LeftHeaderPicture.Width = 80
        .CenterHeader = "&B &22 blah blah"

        .LeftFooter = "&20 &D &T"
        .CenterFooter = "&10 blah blah"
        .RightFooter = "&10 &P of &N"

        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True



    End With
```